# MacBook Pro (April 2010 edition) overheats while running Boot Camp

Tags: macbook, boot-camp

I have a MacBook Pro, 15" April 2010 edition, which overheats and then freezes while running [Boot Camp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_%28software%29).  It appears that the fans aren't turning on.  I run Windows 7 x64.  The CPU is a Core i5.  I see lots of mentions of this on Apple's forums and elsewhere, but no solutions.

I measured the temperature while running Mac OS X and while running Windows 7, and verified that it's simply much hotter under Boot Camp.

What is the reason?

Comment: pretty much the same here (older laptop though, and it never goes hat far that it freezes). I never read a final solution on the net so maybe there is none. As far as I know, it has to do with drivers. In Windows my fans start going berserk even when there's like no cpu usage. Summers are hell.

Comment: @stijn: Are you also using Win7 x64?  I wonder if it's better with the 32 bit version.

Comment: yes x64 here as well. But before that, XP x86 and that was more or less the same. That, combined with the fact that on non-bootcamp laptops the fans act normally under Windows, is why I suspect there is something wrong with an apple-supplied driver. I might be wrong off course. Too bad I haven't any linux distro installed, anyone knows if there's also a heating issue?